# Changing default behavior of Windows' thumbnail caching

Tags: windows, images, windows-explorer, thumbnails

I find it extremely annoying (and ultra lame) that Windows Explorer will only generate thumbnails for those files whose names are visible in the window.  If I open a folder full of photos and walk away for an hour, why the heck wouldn't it generate the thumbnails in the background, so that when I come back I can quickly scroll through the folder and find the photos I want?

Sure, I could import all of the photos into Picasa, but that's not the solution I am looking for.  I really want to find out if there is a way to force Windows Explorer to load all thumbnails in a folder.

Comment: I can't offer a solution, but I just tried it on my WinXP SP3 and it generated thumbnails for all images in the folder, regardless of if they were visible in the window.

Comment: Odd, I've never seen it work in XP SP3 either.  Or Vista.  This is driving me crazy!  :)